# How to call lines that only have one record in a table?

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this;

| Job | Order | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 212 | Error |
| 101 | 212 | Complete |
| 202 | 321 | Error |
| 202 | 321 | Complete |
| 303 | 404 | Error |
| 303 | 404 | Complete |
| 444 | 505 | Error |
| 535 | 667 | Error |

I need to only pull the JOB# that are showing one error line (not an error and complete). The only thing I want to call are

| Job | Order | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 444 | 505 | Error |
| 535 | 667 | Error |

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following:

```
select Job, Order, Status
from t
where t.status = 'Error'
and not exists (
  select * from t t2
  where t2.Job = t.Job and t2.Order = t.Order and t2.Status != t.status
);
```